# CSS Heart with Text within

Tags: css

I would like to put a name into a heart made with CSS. And I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I have this code already:

```
#heart {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

#heart:before,#heart:after {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  left:50px;
  top:0;
  width:50px;
  height:80px;
  background:#F00000;
  -moz-border-radius:50px 50px 0 0;
  border-radius:50px 50px 0 0;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin:0 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin:0 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin:0 100%;
  -o-transform-origin:0 100%;
  transform-origin:0 100%;
}

#heart:after {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin:100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin:100% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin:100% 100%;
  transform-origin:100% 100%;
}
```

When I try to write the name directly into the div: "#heart", it just puts the text behind.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Tip: By changing `#heart` to `.heart`, you can easily add multiple hearts to a page.

Comment: For hearts and other (more complex) shapes, make sure to have a look at the great [Pure CSS icons by Nicolas Gallagher](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-gui-icons/demo/). He managed to create whole range of icons, using only one or two elements each, and a lot of creative CSS.

Answer (score 2):

add a span element

```
<span id="text">Love</span>
```

with css

```
#text{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    margin-left:35px;
    margin-top:25px;
    color:white;
    display:block;
}
```

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FH9S7/

Comment: @Vinm If you name that element `text` it is. But I would rather keep it a div and give it a different class, like `heart-content` (or an id like that, if you must). That will also allow you to add other content including block elements inside it. It just gives you more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `z-index: -1` to the `:before` and `:after` elements. It will move the heart shapes behind the text without needing an extra div.

After that, you can play around a bit with the paddings or text-align to align the text inside the heart:

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/hYEb6/1/

PS: In my fiddle I changed the id to a classname. By doing so, you can easily recycle the styling to add multiple hearts to the page.

-edit-

Maybe you'll like this one. If you *are* going to use an extra element, it's a bit easier to make the heart flexible in size as well:

The HTML can be (using classes again, of course):

```
<div class="heart">
    <div class="inner">
        Test 
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is a little bigger, but scalable:

```
.heart {
  /* The only thing needed to change the size, are these numbers: */
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.heart .inner {
  /* Here is the styling and positioning for your text */
  padding-top: 20%;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* The rest is default, and doesn't need to be modified, unless you want to change background color or other 'heart' properties. */
.heart .inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.heart {
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.heart:after,
.heart .inner:before, 
.heart .inner:after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F00000;
}

.heart:after {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  left: 20%;
  top: 25%;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  border-radius: 0 30% 0 0;
}

.heart .inner:before, 
.heart .inner:after {
  width:58%;
  height:58%;
  -moz-border-radius:50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 5.5%;
}
.heart .inner:before {
    left: 0;
}
.heart .inner:after {
  right: 0%;
}
```

And here's the fiddle showing 3 hearts of different sizes: http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/hYEb6/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use position:absloute, you can do it that way:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/y9e58/

```
<div id="abs">name</div>

#abs{
    position:absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left:40px;
}
```